Did most copyrighted works created prior to 2001 fall into the public domain in North Korea? Their first such law was enacted only in 2001
At least, I have not been able to find any sources of any kind that indicates North Korea had any known copyright laws or regulation whatsoever prior to the 2001 law.
North Korea also acceded to the Berne Convention in 2003, but that seems irrelevant for considering pre 2001 works, unless there is some retroactive law buried in there.
Any thoughts?
Edit: Assuming at least one person in North Korea made at least one copy of each work. Also edited title for clarity as it’s possible some works were locked away and never distributed via any form.

I have a number of books published in the DPRK before 2001, mostly by the Foreign Languages Publishing House, and none of them bear any copyright notices. (I also have books and magazines published after that, and only one of them has a copyright notice.)  Of course, this doesn't definitively answer your question, since copyright may exist even without a notice, though it does suggest that the state-run publishers were not overly concerned with conspicuously asserting so-called IP rights.
